# Get documents which matches the most number of items from a given array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
   "User": { _id: 1, UserName: "username", DisplayName: "DisplayName" },
   "Interests": [1, 4, 7, 25, 30, 34, 46],
   "MinAge": 11,
   "Title": "ad title",
   ...
}
```

I want to select the 10 documents which matches the most number of interests from a given array, like:

```
array = [1,7, 30, 33, 38, 46, 55];
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with unwinding and grouping. You will have to group on unique identifier.

```
db.colName.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$Interests'},
    {$match: {Interests: {$in: [1,7, 30, 33, 38, 46, 55]}}},
    {$group: {_id: '$User.UserName', count: {$sum:1}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}},
    {$limit: 10}

)
```

Comment: What about if "User" is also a document and the current document has more properties? Will your answer work? I have updated my question to you understand.

Comment: And I'm getting "$unwind is not supported".

Comment: mongo version??, unwind introduced in 3.2